# SQL count sum of own id in same table but different column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that references it self (invites). There is a column `invited_by_id` where I'd like to get a count of how many patient_profiles each patient_profile invited. How can I do this? Should I use another SELECT statement or a joins?

I think it will be something like count(SELECT * WHERE p.id = invited_by_id ) but unsure where to put it.

```
SELECT p.first_name,
FROM patient_profiles AS p
```

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a table has a self-reference, you can query it with a self-join:

```
SELECT
    host.id
,   host.first_name
,   host.last_name
,   count(invitee.invited_by_id) as invited_count
FROM patient_profiles AS host
JOIN patient_profiles AS invitee ON invitee.invited_by_id = host.id
GROUP BY host.id, host.first_name, host.last_name
```

The idea is to join the table to itself under different aliases (`host` and `invitee` above). Invitees are linked up to their hosts by `invitee.invited_by_id = host.id` condition. After that the results are flattened with `GROUP BY` to produce a list of profiles, along with the counts.

**Note:** The above will not show profiles that do not invite anybody. If you would like to see them, switch to `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: I would like to use a LEFT OUTER JOIN, what does the count(*) become?

Comment: @user2954587 The count would be 1 before the edit. After the edit it would be zero.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could use a `JOIN` to do that

```
SELECT
    p.id,
    p.first_name,
    COUNT(p2.id) AS "Invitations"
FROM patient_profiles p
    LEFT JOIN patient_profiles p2 ON p2.invited_by_id = p.id
GROUP BY
    p.id,
    p.first_Name
```